# Query Optimization, changing the queries in the loop into a single processing query

Tags: php, sql, fuelphp

How do I optimize these queries to be one or two? The one in the loop to be one at least.

```
$applicantIds = \DB::select()->from( 'applicants' )->where( 'created_at', 0 )->execute();

foreach ($applicantIds as $applicantId) 
{
    $applicantApp = \DB::select( 'applicant_id', 'created_at' )->from( 'applicant_apps' )->where( 'applicant_id', $applicantId['id'] )->execute();

    \DB::update( 'applicants' )->value( 'created_at', $applicantApp[0]['created_at'] )->where( 'id', $applicantApp[0]['applicant_id'] )->execute();
        
}
```

Comment: use join on `applicant_apps` in the first query.

Answer (score 2):

I I understand you, you can use singe query for this:

```
update applicants a
join applicant_apps aa on aa.applicant_id = a.id
set a.created_at = aa.created_at
where a.created_at = 0;
```

When you want to use Laravel syntax:

```
$db::table('applicants as a')
     ->where( $db::raw("`a`.`created_at`"), 0)
     ->join('applicant_apps as aa', 'aa.applicant_id', '=', 'a.id')
     ->update([ 'a.created_at' => $db::raw("`aa`.`created_at`") ])
     ;
```

[Online test](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/684e71c06e3a0a247acea17e60770fb6/php/php81/a20f535144ce44728ba67ccf86e335b7/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```php
$applicantIds = \DB::select()->from( 'applicants' )->where( 'created_at', 0 )->execute();
$applicantApps = \DB::select( 'applicant_id', 'created_at' )->from( 'applicant_apps' )->where( 'applicant_id', 'in', $applicantIds)->execute();

$statement = '';
foreach ($applicantApps as $applicantApp) 
{
   $applicantId = $applicantApp['applicant_id'];
   $applicantCreatedAt = $applicantApp['created_at'];
   $statement .= "update applicants set created_at='$applicantCreatedAt' where id = '$applicantId';"
}

if ($statement) {
   \DB::query($statement)->execute();
}
```

Two queries only will get you this.

And you can add some logic in foreach block if you need.

Comment: This worked well but I had to convert the ID's to an array so that they can be used in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

@faesal with your answer I changed it to have some arrays as ID's

```
$applicantIds = \DB::select('id')->from( 'applicants' )->where( 'created_at', 0 )->execute()->as_array('id');

$applicantApps = \DB::select( 'applicant_id', 'created_at' )->from( 'applicant_apps' )->where( 'applicant_id', 'in', array_keys($applicantIds))->execute();

$statement = '';
foreach ($applicantApps as $applicantApp) 
{
    $applicantId = $applicantApp['applicant_id'];
    $applicantCreatedAt = $applicantApp['created_at'];
    $statement .= "update applicants set created_at='$applicantCreatedAt' where id = '$applicantId';";
}

\DB::query($statement)->execute();
```